# About a pictorial proof of uniform continuity by D. M. Bloom

Tags: calculus, education

I read "A Pictorial Proof of Uniform Continuity" by D. M. Bloom and I had a question.

Here is the proof:

Suppose that $\varepsilon$ is any positive real number, $I = [a, b], f(x)$ is continuous on $I$ , $S = \{(x,y) \in I \times I \vert \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \ge \varepsilon \}$ and $F(x,y) = \vert x - y \vert$.

Then, $\{(x,y) \in I \times I \vert x = y \} \cap S = \emptyset$.
and $S$ is a bounded closed set. So $F(x,y)$ has a positive minimum value on $S$.

Let the positive minimum value be $\delta$.Then $\vert f(x) - f(y) \vert \ge \varepsilon \Rightarrow \vert x - y \vert \ge \delta$, i.e. $\vert x - y \vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon$

This shows $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $I$.

My question is the following:

If S is an empty set, this proof doesn't work.

Am I correct?

Comment: It works. because $S$ is still closed and bounded vacuously, and $S \cap \{ (x,y) \in I \times I | |f(x)-f(y) | \geq \epsilon \} = \phi$ anyway. The proof changes slightly in that now, any $\delta$ works since $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ is true all the time.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: +1 goes for a totally new proof (at least for me). Although i must say it uses function of two variables to prove a property of function of a single variable.